# How to get the product url in Easy digital download?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am using **easy digital download** (https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/) for selling digital product. Need to know how to get the product attachment url  .How can i place   download link near purchase button. ? or how can i replace purchase button with download link ? .This for my custom requirements. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post a message on the plugin support page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the attachment url in product single page  by

```
$d_links=get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'edd_download_files', true );
```

If you need to display the attachment url near purchase button

then place the following code in easy-digital-downloads/includes/templatefunction.php

```
$d_links=get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'edd_download_files', true );
    foreach($d_links as $d_link){

    $d_s_link=$d_link['file'];
    echo '<a href='.$d_s_link.' class="edd_download_file_link">Download</a><br>';

    }
```

under  **function edd_get_purchase_link( $args = array() )**

Note: this is only attachment url .Here i don't include code for force download.You can only view this file when clicking the download link,not force download your product .

Comment: Thanks. That work .Can you tell me how to make it as a force  download  rater than normal link.

Comment: make download=""                                                            ie     echo '<a href='.$d_s_link.' class="edd_download_file_link" download="">Download</a><br>';